# Problema con validación en horas MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Estoy creando la base de datos para una barberia donde se necesita validar que no hayan reservas de tal hora a tal hora, por ejemplo, se sabe que las sesiones de la barbería duran 30 minutos, por lo que si se reserva una cita a las 8:00 am entonces la hora final va a ser a las 8:30 am, he intentado hacer una procedure donde se valide eso mismo usando mayor que y menor que, sin embargo cuando se reserva una cita usando el mismo ejemplo anterior a las 8:10 am si lo deja pasar y el la cita se agenda.

Este es el procedure,

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CITAS_INSERT(
ID_USR_FK_PR INT,
ID_TRAB_FK_PR INT,
ID_SERV_FK_PR INT,
FECHA_PR DATE,
HORA_INICIO_PR TIME
)
BEGIN 
    SET @HORA_FINAL = (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(STR_TO_DATE(HORA_INICIO_PR, '%H:%i:%s'), '00:30:00'), '%H:%i:%s'));
    IF( NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CITAS WHERE FECHA =  FECHA_PR AND HORA_INICIO >= HORA_INICIO_PR AND HORA_FINAL <= @HORA_FINAL AND ID_TRAB_FK = ID_TRAB_FK_PR)) THEN
        INSERT INTO CITAS(ID_USR_FK, ID_TRAB_FK, ID_SERV_FK, FECHA, HORA_INICIO, HORA_FINAL) VALUES (ID_USR_FK_PR, ID_TRAB_FK_PR, ID_SERV_FK_PR, FECHA_PR, HORA_INICIO_PR, @HORA_FINAL);
    END IF;
END //
```

Cuando llamo el procedure de esta forma, se guardan los datos correctamente.

```
CALL SP_CITAS_INSERT(1,1,1,'2022-07-26','08:00:00');
```

Si lo llamo de nuevo pero ahora le cambio la hora de inicio así, los datos se guardan y no deberían de guardarse porque la sesión dura 30 minutos, es decir, entre las 8:00 y las 8:30 no debería aceptar citas.

```
CALL SP_CITAS_INSERT(1,1,1,'2022-07-26','08:10:00');
```

Comment: Analizando tu consulta sin correrlo, con los datos de ejemplo (y si no me perdí en las comparaciones): ¿`HORA_INICIO >= HORA_INICIO_PR`: '08:00:00' >= '08:10:00'? no; ¿`HORA_FINAL <= @HORA_FINAL`: '08:30:00' <= '08:40:00'? Sí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te propongo una solución un poco más sencilla a partir de un dataset simplificado:

```
CREATE TABLE citas(
  id_cita int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  fecha datetime
  );

CREATE PROCEDURE insertar_cita(vfecha datetime)
  BEGIN
    IF (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM citas
        WHERE vfecha
        BETWEEN fecha
        AND fecha+INTERVAL 29 MINUTE
      )=0 THEN INSERT INTO citas (fecha) VALUES (vfecha);
    END if;
  END;

CALL insertar_cita('2022-07-26 8:00');
CALL insertar_cita('2022-07-26 8:15');
CALL insertar_cita('2022-07-26 8:30');
SELECT * FROM citas;
```

Verás que únicamente se registran las citas que respeten media hora desde el inicio de la anterior, independientemente de la hora de inicio:

```
+---------+---------------------+
| id_cita | fecha               |
+---------+---------------------+
|       1 | 2022-07-26 08:00:00 |
|       2 | 2022-07-26 08:30:00 |
+---------+---------------------+
```

Espero que te resulte de utilidad. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios para mejorar todo lo posible la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias David, me ha ayudado muchísimo. Te agradezco!!